# Nullable Owned types in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I my case I want to store an address but it has to be optional.

My mapping lookes like this:

```
map.OwnsOne(x => x.Address, cb => cb.OwnsOne(l => l.Location));
```

But when comitting my DbContext with Address as null iam getting this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The entity of 'Member' is sharing the table
>   'Members' with 'Member.Address#StreetAddress', but there is no entity
>   of this type with the same key value 'Id:-2147480644' that has been
>   marked as 'Added'.

I then instantiated the Address and Location from the constructors, and now I can save the entity. But when fetching the data again I also gets an instantiated Address, where i really wanted a null value.

Is it not possible to make nullable Owned Types ?

Comment: is there any reason you are using the fluent API mapping rather than property mapping? A member can have an address, but every address must belong to a member. Ensure that you have a MemberId (foreign key) in your Address class, and also ensure that you have a `public virtual Address Address { get; set; }` in your Member class - warning: this is untested.

Comment: The short answer is no. Owned types are pretty much like EF6 Complex Types and are required and always loaded as part of the owner data.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: I like keeping my domain object clean and mapping separated in its own file. I want the address to be spread on columns on the entity like Address_Streetname, Address_City etc. so there should be no need for a reference id to the member? Maybe I wanted to add an address field to an order entity.

Comment: @IvanStoev: I see, found some documentation this morning. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/implement-value-objects

Comment: Any suggestions to how I can have a value type like address that uses table splitting and allowing null values?

Comment: I don't understand how your tables are structured. is it possible to add a .png image to explain what you are doing?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon : Right now I only have a member table trying to make this work, but I want to have en uniform way of storing an address or other stuff that have the same structure across entities, without saving them in a separate table for that type of data.

Comment: Post current schema?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NWE5cd_PknBA16JuTirypI46O1M0EjD2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @RuneJensen How did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 8):

> Is it not possible to make nullable Owned Types?

As of EF Core 3, this is now possible .

> all dependents are now optional. (Shipping in preview 4): 
>   [Source](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9005#issuecomment-477741082)

---

[Sample Code](https://github.com/spottedmahn/EntityFramework.Docs/tree/null-owned-type-3.0/samples/core/Modeling/OwnedEntities):

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  using (var context = new OwnedEntityContext())
  {
    context.Add(new DetailedOrder
    {
      Status = OrderStatus.Pending,
      OrderDetails = new OrderDetails
      {
        ShippingAddress = new StreetAddress
        {
          City = "London",
          Street = "221 B Baker St"
        }
        //testing 3.0: "Yes, all dependents are now optional"
        //reference: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9005#issuecomment-477741082
        //NULL Owned Type Testing
        //BillingAddress = new StreetAddress
        //{
        //    City = "New York",
        //    Street = "11 Wall Street"
        //}
      }
    });
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
  //read test
  using (var context = new OwnedEntityContext())
  {
    #region DetailedOrderQuery
    var order = context.DetailedOrders.First(o => o.Status == OrderStatus.Pending);
    Console.Write("NULL Owned Type Test, Is Billing Address NULL?");
    //PRINTS FALSE
    Console.WriteLine($"{order.OrderDetails.BillingAddress == null}");
    #endregion
  }
}
```

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    #region OwnsOneNested
    modelBuilder.Entity<DetailedOrder>().OwnsOne(p => p.OrderDetails, od =>
    {
        od.OwnsOne(c => c.BillingAddress);
        od.OwnsOne(c => c.ShippingAddress);
    });
    #endregion

    #region OwnsOneTable
    modelBuilder.Entity<DetailedOrder>().OwnsOne(p => p.OrderDetails, od =>
    {
        od.OwnsOne(c => c.BillingAddress);
        od.OwnsOne(c => c.ShippingAddress);
        od.ToTable("OrderDetails");
        //Exception message:Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
        //'Cascading foreign key 'FK_OrderDetails_DetailedOrders_OrderId' cannot
        //be created where the referencing column 'OrderDetails.OrderId' is an identity column.
        //Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.'
        //3.0 bug: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/17448#issuecomment-525444101 
        //fixed in 3.1: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/pull/17458
        od.Property("OrderId")
            .ValueGeneratedNever();
    });
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: [documentation request](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/1646)

Comment: Explained in more detail by Julie Lehrman here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/data-points-backing-field-and-owned-entity-changes-in-ef-core-3-0#important-changes-to-owned-entities-in-ef-core-30. There is still one issue with nullable owned types that will be fixed in EF Core 3.1: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/17422

Answer (score 6):

One of the limitations of Owned Types is that no support for optional (i.e. nullable).
I recommend you to follow [this thread](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9005).

In my solution, I use the Empty Object approach and use the IsEmpty method to know if an Address is Empty instead of asking if the address is null. I hope this approach helps you.

```
public sealed class Address : ValueObject<Address>
{
    public string StreetAddress1 { get; private set; }
    public string StreetAddress2 { get; private set; }
    public string City { get; private set; }
    public string State { get; private set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; private set; }
    public string Country { get; private set; }

    private Address() { }
    public Address(string streetAddress1, string city, string state, string zipcode, string country)
    {
        StreetAddress1 = streetAddress1;
        City = city;
        State = state;
        ZipCode = zipcode;
        Country = country;
    }

    public Address(string streetAddress1, string streetAddress2, string city, string state, string zipcode, string country)
        : this(streetAddress1, city, state, zipcode, country)
    {
        StreetAddress2 = streetAddress2;
    }

    public static Address Empty()
    {
        return new Address("", "", "", "", "");
    }

    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StreetAddress1)
         && string.IsNullOrEmpty(City)
         && string.IsNullOrEmpty(State)
         && string.IsNullOrEmpty(ZipCode)
         && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Country))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
public class Firm : AggregateRoot<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Address Address { get; private set; }

    private Firm() { }
    public Firm(string name)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            throw new ArgumentException();

        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Name = name;
        Address = Address.Empty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Entity Framework [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#current-shortcomings) states that

> Reference navigations to owned entity types cannot be null unless they
>   are explicitly mapped to a separate table from the owner

So, in fact, there is a solution to your problem. You need to map your owned entity to a separate table instead of having it inside the same table as the owner.

```
map.OwnsOne(x => x.Address, cb => cb.OwnsOne(l => l.Location, l=> l.ToTable("Locations")));
```

By mapping the location entity into a separate table called ***Locations***, the owned entity becomes nullable.

Answer (score 4):

As of EF 6.0, there as been a [breaking change](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/main/entity-framework/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/breaking-changes.md#nested-optionals) on how to handle nullable owned types ([here is the discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/9005#issuecomment-1077893828)).

The default nullability is based on the fact that your owned type has exclusively nullable properties or not.

```
//This is how to force a nullable owned type, even thought it's properties aren't all nullable
ob.OwnsOne(o => o.ShippingAddress);
ob.Navigation(o => o.ShippingAddress).IsRequired(false);
```

Comment: You, sir, saved my day. Here, have my vote.

Comment: And in what circumstance will this property be nullable if its subproperties are not nullable on database?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt846463.aspx and scroll down to "Temporary Work-Around to Allow Null Value Objects".

A shorter example can be found here: https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/48063630/nullable-owned-types-in-ef-core

I would be nice to be able to do this without this workaround, but I don't believe that's possible yet.