# EF Core 3.1 value object is nullable after add migration, while in Fluent API it's mandatory

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-3.1

I have created a `ValueObject` called `Discount` as below:

```
public class Discount:ValueObject
{
    public int          Value { get; }
    public DiscountUnit Unit  { get; }
    // Code removed for brevity
}
```

In FluentApi configuration I use the `OwnsOne` method like this:

```
builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Discount, b => {
                                          b.Property(x => x.Value)
                                              .IsRequired(true);
                                          b.Property(x => x.Unit)
                                              .HasConversion(s => s.ToString(),
                                                             x => (DiscountUnit) Enum.Parse( typeof(DiscountUnit), x))
                                              .IsRequired(true);
                                        } );
```

When I update the database, `Value` and `Unit` are nullable while they are required.

Comment: [Does this post useful to you ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48063630/nullable-owned-types-in-ef-core)